# What does this example bash startup script do?

Tags: mac, bash, terminal

I am trying to set up GNU Octave on my computer (Mac OS X 10.7.4). I am newbie in using Terminal and I need help to understand what the following script actually does:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ];then<br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;. ~/.bashrc<br>
fi<br>
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin<br>
BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc<br>
export BASH_ENV PATH<br>
export GNUTERM=aqua<br>
alias octave="/Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/bin/octave"<br>
alias gnuplot="/Applications/Gnuplot.app/Contents/Resources/bin/gnuplot"<br>
```

(taken from here: http://wikibox.stanford.edu/me112/index.php/Main/OctaveMatlabNotes)

So this script begins with the simple conditional if statement. I don't understand the conditional expression - what is -f and .bashrc? What the statement . ~/.bashrc actually does?

Then 2 variables are defined PATH and BASH_ENV. Why are they exported? Why GNUTERM=aqua is exported even if it's not defined anywhere?

All I need is a script that would allow me to run Octave by simply typing octave in the terminal. I don't need an alias for the gnu plot.

Thanks

Comment: Try `man bash`. Come back with specific questions once you've tried to understand it.

Comment: @DanielBeck I agree he should read the bash documentation, but sending a Terminal newbie to a man page *in the terminal* is torture. He'd have to learn how to navigate his default pager (more/less) first, which becomes a chicken-and-egg problem. Better to send him to a [web-based copy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html) first.

Comment: @Spiff Well, typing `man bash` into the web search box and feeling lucky works just as well. Or downloading the [man pages app for iOS](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/man-pages-freebsd-7.1/id306654412?mt=8) and browsing them on a phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[ -f ]` tests if a file exists.

The tilde `~` is shell shorthand for your home/user directory. Files personal to you are stored there. `~/.bashrc`, if it exists, is another `bash` startup file, in your home directory, that usually gets run when you start `bash` interactively (that is, when you're not just calling `bash` to execute a pre-existing `bash` script file). The example file you're looking at is probably meant to be a `.profile`, which is another shell startup script that typically only gets run when you're first logging into the system. If you have commands you only want run when you log in, you put them in `~/.profile`. If you have commands that set up your interactive shell environment (like aliases that make commands easier to invoke), then you put them in your `.bashrc`. Since login shells are also interactive shells, you usually want your `.profile` to also load ("source") your `.bashrc`.

When your shell looks for commands to run, it consults the environment variable `PATH`. This line exports it so that other commands you invoke from the shell know where to find other commands. It also adds the directory `/usr/local/bin` to the `PATH` so that the shell and programs it runs also looks for commands there.

`BASH_ENV` defines what startup script `bash` should run if it's being invoked in a non-login, non-interactive situation. I guess it's being exported so that if you invoke a non-interactive `bash` instance (like to execute a pre-existing script file), it will still run your `.bashrc`. I don't usually want non-interactive shells running my `.bashrc`, so I would never define `BASH_ENV` the way it is defined in this example file you found.

`GNUTERM` is defined as being the string `aqua`. It's being defined and exported at the same time. Since you're on a Mac, which might not have XWindows (X11) installed, this is telling your GNUTerm/GNUPlot/GNUOctave environment what tool to run to draw your plots to the screen. Probably [aquaterm](http://aquaterm.sourceforge.net/), which you might want to make sure you've installed if you haven't already. I don't know about the whole Mac variants  of the GNUOctave/GNUPlot/GNUterm/aquaterm ecosystem, so I can't advise you on the nitty-gritty details.